# Sharing Facebook open graph action succeeds, but post isn't visible

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm migrating a legacy app from facebook iOS SDK 2.x to 3.x, and I'm having trouble getting my open graph object to share successfully.

Here's the code I have to share the object:

```
NSMutableDictionary *properties = [@{
                                    @"og:type": @"my-app:my-object",
                                    @"og:title": @"Title",
                                    @"og:description": @"text",
                                    } mutableCopy];

if(photoUrl){
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoUrl] userGenerated:NO];
    properties[@"og:image"] = @[photo];
}

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject* graphObject = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"my-app:my-action";
[action setObject:graphObject forKey:@"my-object"];

FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"my-object";

FBSDKShareAPI* shareAPI = [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:[ShareDelegate theShareDelegate]];

if(![shareAPI share]){
    NSLog(@"![shareAPI share]");
    onFail(nil);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Share succeeded");
    onFinish();
}
```

The share action appears to succeed.  The delegate method `-(void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results` is called with this results dictionary:

```
{
    completionGesture = post;
    postId = 1608774589402167;
}
```

But the post doesn't appear in the test user's news feed.  Also, on the *open graph -> action types* section of the app dashboard at https://developers.facebook.com I see this error message:

```
Your Open Graph action failed to publish on any of the Platforms you submitted. Make sure the action is working properly by publishing the action with a test user before resubmitting.
```

This graph action was being shared successfully using the Facebook 2.x SDK for iOS.

What could the point of failure be?

Comment: Check the test user’s activity log and see if the post shows up there.

Comment: The posts are showing up in the activity log but not in the timeline - any idea why?

Comment: The Facebook iOS SDK is now at version 4. I would recommend first upgrading to that one. Second, check the updated documentation (Setting the image on the action, not the object might change). Also, it is not guaranteed to be posted on the person's timeline, but if it succeeded, it will definitely show in the Activity Log.

Comment: @sak If you don't mind looking at my recent question, I am having trouble using the reserved "save" action with these posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need the answer here, but to get the action to show in the users' timeline you need to set the key on your action:

```
[action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
```

This requires configuration for your custom action as well (check boxes at the bottom of the page).